# Red Hat 7 NOPASSWD for a specific script

Tags: sudo, rhel7, sudoers

Say I have a script called `sayhi.sh` at `/usr/local/bin/` directory. And I have a user called `tim` who needs to run this script as `sudo /usr/local/bin/sayhi.sh` without the password.

So I updated the /etc/sudoers file as follows:

```
tim ALL =(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/sayhi.sh
```

But still when running it, it asks for the password. But If i updated the `sudoers` file as follows, it runs without asking the password.

```
tim ALL =(root) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But I want specifically say that I want `tim` to run only `/usr/local/bin/sayhi.sh` without asking for the password.

And permissions for sayhi.sh is is as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13 May  2 10:14 sayhi.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the /etc/sudoers file and write the correct entry as follows:

```
tim ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/sayhi.sh
```